# Glide, Recyclerview and OOM

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory, android-glide

I'm using **Glide** to load images in my app, I'm using it to show some images in **RecyclerView** items.

this is my adapter for recyclerview :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.Holder>{

private Context context;

private ArrayList<DataImages.DataImage> images;

public MyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<DataImages.DataImage> images){
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int type){
    return new VollipsHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.m_layout, viewGroup));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position){
    DataImages.DataImage dataImage = images.get(position);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(dataImage.thumb)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_placeholder)
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(holder.getImageView());
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(Holder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    Glide.clear(holder.getImageView());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){return images.size();}

class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView imageView;

    public Holder (View view){
        super(view);

        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.m_image);
    }

    public ImageView getImageView(){return imageView;}

}

}
```

everything is working fine, except **Bitmap** or **Drawable** from ImageViews won't remove from **memory** when items are detached from window or better say, when items are not visible.

and after scrolling for like 1 minute i get **out of memory exception**.

as you can see I'm using `Glide.clear()` method for this problem but it's not working.

any suggestions on this problem ?

Comment: Are you by chance using a `RecyclerView` inside a `ScrollView`?

Comment: @GVillani82 no it's just a RecyclerView, btw nested scrolling is disabled too

Comment: You found any solution to this?

Comment: @Martín no i didn't :(

Comment: What's the size of your images?

Comment: @Martín they are thumbnails, about 150×150px

Comment: @Martín still no solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add in your Activity or Fragment these two methods:

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
  super.onTrimMemory(level);
  Glide.with(this).onTrimMemory(level);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
  super.onLowMemory();
  Glide.with(this).onLowMemory();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the context that is passed into the Adapter's constructor for the `Glide.with(context)` call, try using the ImageView's context.

Glide recycles and handles images depending on the lifecycle of the context you're passing in, so it's always best to pass in the "smallest" context possible.

So it'd look like this:

```
Glide.with(holder.getImageView().getContext())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but nothing changed.